# Design Sync won't revert local changes

Tags: checkout, revert, dssc

I am using the command

```
dssc pop -get -unify path_to_file
```

to locally modify a file and when i try to revert the changes with

```
dssc cancel -force path_to_file
```

I get an error "Error: path_to_file - Object does not exist"

Same issue exists without -force flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something that might help:

If you take a look at any file under control by the dssc (ls -l) that you haven't yet checked out, you can easily discover that the file is actually a link to the vault.

So, when you actually populate a file by using dssc pop -get -uni, what happens is that the tool goes to the vault and fetches a local copy for you.

Now, the above sentence has the actual answer to your question: all you need to do is to actually use dssc pop -get -uni one more time... Well, the tool will probably disagree, recognizing that you've tampered with the file and prompting you to use the -force switch if you really want to revert (repopulate) your file.

Hope this does the trick.